# iframe loading issue in Iphone iOS browser, website crashes

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iframe, safari

There are two nested iframe in my website, one inside

First Iframe - content.html

content.html

```
    <body>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="test.html" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            document.getElementById("iframe").setAttribute("style","height:"+h+"px !important;width:100%");
            window.onresize = function(event) {
                var h = window.innerHeight;
                document.getElementById("iframe").setAttribute("style","height:"+h+"px !important;width:100%");                
            };
    </script>
```

test.html

```
<body>
<iframe id="iframe" src="hello.html" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        document.getElementById("iframe").setAttribute("style","height:"+h+"px !important;width:100%");
        window.onresize = function(event) {
            var h = window.innerHeight;
            document.getElementById("iframe").setAttribute("style","height:"+h+"px !important;width:100%");                
        };
</script>
```

When I open content.html in Iphone(IOS 9,10) browsers safari, chrome browser then the website doesn't load properly and crashes.

If anyone has solution than let me know.